# How to load images just when are needed? (jquery and js)

Tags: jquery

like in this site: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/

it only loads the image when you are rally seeing it. This is something i would want to implement in my website. thanks

and a preloader if possible. i use jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) will load images only when you require them.  Check out the [Preload](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Preload) plugin for... you guessed it... preloading.

Comment: @Andy E totally awesome answer +1